# How do I use sqlite3_exec() Callback

Tags: c++, sqlite

How do I use the callback function to print the details of the albums in the sql table?

```
int DataBaseAccess::_callbackPrintAlbums(void* data, int argc, char** argv, char** azColName)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < argc; i++)
    {
        // ???
    }

    return 0;
}

void DataBaseAccess::printAlbums()
{
    _sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM ALBUMS;";

    _res = sqlite3_exec(_db, _sqlQuery.c_str(), _callbackPrintAlbums, nullptr, &_errMsg);

    if (_res != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        throw MyException("SQL Query failed - " + std::string(_errMsg));
    }
}
```

Comment: Printing out results of a query with no user-supplied values is about the *only* thing that callback interface is okay for, btw. Normally you'll want to use [prepared statements](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/stmt.html)

Comment: And... You just print out the current row's values in a loop.